# Angular directive making required field readonly

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, required

I'm trying to make a input field required and readonly.

The html standard does not allow this, so I tried to make my own directive for it, but the `keydown/keypress` bind is never made. Is there a way around this and why this does not work?

```
ngApp.directive('required', function() {
    return {
        require: '?input',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope,$element,$attr) {
                 if ($attr.hasOwnProperty('readonly')) {
                      $element.removeAttr('readonly');
                      $element.bind('keydown keypress', function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                      });
                 }
         }
    };
});
```

[plnkr.co/edit/XhTxPpqnKwSFKJflSHZW?p=preview](http://www.plnkr.co/edit/XhTxPpqnKwSFKJflSHZW?p=preview) .... second text field, required is never validated by the system!

cheers

c_bb

Comment: Doesn't make sense: it's either readonly or not.

Comment: @dfsq - yes, but accordingly to the html standard the required attribute is overruled if the readonly attribute is set, and i want the field to be both required and readonly!

Comment: I'm confused for the use case.  If the field is read only and the input is required, but not filled in, then what is the user to do?  Or are you purposely trying to annoy them? (not trying to be sarcastic, just trying to understand the use case)

Comment: @pgreen2 - user have a list of persons they select from, then they click 'add person' button and the field is set via code! user has do it this way to make sure person_id is also set, which it won't if they type the person them self. could we please try to stay on topic :-)

Comment: Don't see any problem you describe, both required and readonly behave as expected. http://plnkr.co/edit/OaSpZPJdEovgz9EPITH7?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq - try removing novalidate since it need to validate! and add a submit button, then you will see it ignores required!

Comment: Well, first of all you *do* want `novalidate` attribute. But anyway, I can't replicate the issue. You can create a demo, otherwise it's hard to help without clear reprodusable demo.

Comment: @dfsq - ehm, no I don't want novalidate, I have no use for it in my code! .... example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XhTxPpqnKwSFKJflSHZW?p=preview .... second text field, required is never validated by the system! and before answering with 'then you can't complete the form', please read the other comments!

Comment: Works as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/IUjcjL1znUBsgqACO3YA?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq - yes, that is beautiful ... if there is somebody that have a useful answer to my question, it world be much appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I gave you the answer to your problem, seems that you don't really understand why you do need novalidate attribute and how you should handle form submision (not how you are trying to do it). But this is another story.

Comment: @dfsq is right, please see answer with an explanation and suggested resolution below.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I just re-read your question and thought about it again, and my original answer is crap.  You really do want `novalidate` on your form, and then you show errors in an angular type way rather than trying to use html form validation, which isn't going to work for you for the reasons you mention in the comments.

You want your form to looks something like this:

```
    <form name="testForm" ng-submit="submitForm(testForm.$valid)" novalidate >
    <input type="text" name="value" ng-model="test1" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="value2" ng-model="test2" required readonly><br>
    <p ng-show="testForm.value2.$error.required" class="help-block">Please select a whatever</p>

    <input type="submit" ng-click='testForm.$valid && mySubmitFunction()'>

</form>
```

This will give you an error message based on the stock angular validation for `required`.

and you need some kind of a submit handler in your controller, like this:

```
 $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

// check to make sure the form is completely valid
if (isValid) {
  alert('our form is amazing');
} else {
  console.log('fail')
}
```

};

Do whatever sensible things you need in the submit function.

//OLD, TERRIBLE ANSWER BELOW

If the readonly attribute does indeed override the required attribute the 'proper' solution would probably to write some custom validation (see article at http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Writing_Custom_Validitions/).

However, if you just want a cheap way out, you could put a `ng-minlength=1` requirement on the input.  If the user can't put anything in the field manually, and there has to be something in the field for it to be valid, I think you've basically got what you want.